# Firefox scripting: Attach a python script to a firefox hotkey

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is it possible to call a python script, invoked by a firefox hotkey?

Basically I would like to be able to type +P (for example) and call a script where I could access the current Firefox environment and do stuff.

In particular, I would like to grab the current url and appended it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I need to write an addon to firefox. Found this blog entry that explains it [here](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=511)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found any simple extension can invoked a hotkey to call a script. Vimperator can do this but it maybe a bit complex.

I think the easy way is use FireGesutres extension script, invoked it by mouse gesutres. I write a script to call Chrome to open current url.

https://github.com/muzuiget/firegestures-scripts/blob/master/open_in_other_browser.js

Just replace `BROWSER` variable to your python script path, the argument is current url.